# sudo gitlab-runner result command not found but gitlab-runner only can run

Tags: gitlab, centos7, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

My Environment is Centos 7, I just installed gitlab-runner and when I run this command as User that installing the gitlab-runner (not as root)

```
sudo gitlab-runner register
```

this will result command not found but if I run without sudo

```
gitlab-runner register
```

it runs but it shows this lines

```
WARNING: Running in user-mode.
WARNING: The user-mode requires you to manually start builds processing:
WARNING: $ gitlab-runner run
WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:
WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...
```

Is anybody know how to fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I uninstalled and installed the gitlab-runner using yum install following [this instruction](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html)

Answer (score 5):

you can modify the file '/etc/sudoers', find  "Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin  ", change it as "Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"。

i just solved the issue by above operation.